# Why does this reverse stack function return undefined instead of expected output?

Tags: javascript, stack

The output is undefined. I am unable to see what is wrong with the code, it is probably something small.. any help? Input 123, expected output 321.

```js
var reverse = function(x) {
  var stack = [];
  var number;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    stack.push(x);
  }

  while (stack.length > 0) {
    number += stack.pop();
  }

  return number;
};

console.log(reverse(123));
```

Comment: Please give input and expected output...

Comment: `123` does not have a `length` property, that's one problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are making three mistakes:

- You need to convert number to string first.
- The second mistake is you are pushing `x` the whole number to `stack` push the char at that index.
- You need to set the `number` initially to `''` not `undefined`

```js
var reverse = function(x) {
  x = String(x)
  var stack=[];
  var number = '';
  for(var i =0;i<x.length;i++){
    stack.push(x[i])
  }

  while(stack.length >0){
    number += stack.pop();
  }
  return +number;
};

console.log(reverse(123))
```

I think its better to convert number to array of string and then loop through half of the array to reverse it. And in the end use `join()`

```js
var reverse = function(x) {
  x = String(x).split('');
  for(let i = 0;i<Math.floor(x.length/2);i++){
    let temp = x[i];
    x[i] = x[x.length - i - 1];
    x[x.length - i - 1] = temp;
  }
  return x.join('')
 
};

console.log(reverse(123))
```

The above code is best when you don't want to use `reverse()`. With `reverse()` you can make a one-liner

```js
var reverse = x => +String(x).split('').reverse().join('')
console.log(reverse(123))
```

Comment: note that if the expected output is a number you can use return parseInt(number, 10)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that i have to convert to string. Why is not possible to work with integers?

Comment: Also, It should be able to reverse strings too, why is the case that when you input -123 the value is undefined?

Comment: @IanMillan I am not sure what you mean. _"It should be able to reverse strings too"_. But `-123` is a number

Comment: Because when you say "     x = String(x)     it is converting into a string right?

Answer (score 0):

Using the spread operator `...` to split the string (is equivalent, in this case, to `s.split('')`). `reverse` the array and then concatenate using `join('')`.

```js
const reverse = (s) => {
  let isNumber = typeof s === 'number'
  if (isNumber) s += ''; // Convert to string
  
  let result = [...s].reverse().join('');
  
  return isNumber ? parseInt(result) : result;
}

console.log(reverse(123));
```

**EDIT:** handles numbers as well as strings